# HyperX alloy FPS stop working on my macbook

Tags: usb, keyboard, macbook-pro, thunderbolt

I'm using HyperX alloy FPS keyboard with my MacBook Pro 15 inches 2017 for a half a year, keyboard connected with my mac through Samsung C34J79 monitor (keyboard connected to monitor by 2 USB type A and monitor to my mac by Thunderbolt). Everything was perfect until today.  I disconnect my MacBook from the monitor as I needed to go to another place, and when I connected it again my keyboard stop working... all keys are glowing as before but MacBook not acting when I press the keys at all.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I tried to hold FN+ESC on the keyboard to make a factory reset but it not solve the issue

Comment: as I remember when I connect it by the first time, MacBook showed me the pop-up with the configuration of the new keyboard, but now I do not see that pop-up so I can assume mac book see the keyboard?